# Import error from packages in python

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am trying to use LDA in python, however, each time I import something from a package I get such an error. 

I tried importing choose from utils, it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omaral-assaf/Documents/lld.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import choose
ImportError: cannot import name 'choose'
```

Comment: Why do you think "utils" is the `utils` in LDA?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the solution to the error, HOWEVER, what I used as an alternative that helped me do what I needed was, I used spyder from anaconda. All packages are installed so it made it easier to use

useful links:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos